# Issue with Chrome CI/CD "Chrome unable to launch with Github Action

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, automation, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm trying to intergrate CI/CD into my project. The project using mocha typescript with selenium. I can't figure out why Chrome isn't launch. Everything works fine on my local machine. I hope this is not too broad of a question because I've just started implementing CI/CD into my project.

[image]

Not sure where I can find other solution but this is the latest log.
https://github.com/AxelAlinsky/saucedemo-workspace-automation/actions/runs/7079676996/job/19266591612

After implementing the yml file for the github action to run the CI/CD Chrome should launch and run the automation test

Comment: Looks like your latest workflows with headless browser are passing.